# Magento 2 : Add values to ui_component fields

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I've created custom **Admin Grid** with Default Magento's Customer Collection.

I am sharing my code for this.

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="credit_grid_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">customer_entity</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\Data\GridInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Grid" />
```

**Below is Layout for `adminhtml`**

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="credit_grid_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> ../layout/credit_grid_addrow.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
       <block class="Vednor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\AddRow" name="add_row" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

> ui_component/credit_grid_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing.credit_grid_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing.credit_grid_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">grid_records_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Row</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="credit_grid_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing.credit_grid_listing.grid_records_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing.credit_grid_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing.credit_grid_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing.credit_grid_listing.grid_records_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing.credit_grid_listing.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/massdelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing.credit_grid_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">credit_grid_listing.credit_grid_listing.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
<columns name="grid_records_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
               <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </selectionsColumn>
   <column name="firstname">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">firstname</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </column>
   <column name="lastname" >
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">lastname</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </column>

   <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
               <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
               <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

> ../Model/ResourceModel/Grid.php

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('customer_entity', 'entity_id');
}
```

> ../Model/Grid.php

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid');
}

public function getEntityId()
{
    return $this->getData(self::ENTITY_ID);
}


public function setEntityId($entityId)
{
    return $this->setData(self::ENTITY_ID, $entityId);
}


public function getFirstname()
{
    return $this->getData(self::FIRSTNAME);
}


public function setFirstname($firstName)
{
    return $this->setData(self::FIRSTNAME, $firstName);
}


public function getLastname()
{
    return $this->getData(self::LASTNAME);
}


public function setLastname($lastName)
{
    return $this->setData(self::LASTNAME, $lastName);
}
```

> ../Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/AddRow.php

```
public function execute()
{

    $rowId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
    $rowData = $this->gridFactory->create();

    if ($rowId) {
        $rowData = $rowData->load($rowId);

        $rowTitle = $rowData->getFirstname().'&nbsp;'.$rowData->getLastname();
        if (!$rowData->getFirstName()) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('row data no longer exist.'));
            $this->_redirect('credit/grid/rowdata');
            return;
        }
    }

    $this->coreRegistry->register('row_data', $rowData);
    $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    $title = $rowId ? __('Edit Customer ').$rowTitle : __('Add Row Data');
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($title);
    return $resultPage;
}
```

> ../Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Edit/Form.php

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $id = $this->request->getParam('id');
    $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
    //print_r($model->getData()); exit;
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => [
                        'id' => 'edit_form',
                        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                        'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                        'method' => 'post'
                    ]
        ]
    );

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('troogrid__');
    if ($model->getFirstName()) {
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Edit Customer Social Details'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );
        $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'entity_id']);
    } else {
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Add Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );
    }

    $fieldset->addField(
        'First Name',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'firstname',
            'label' => __('First Name'),
            'value' => 'Data',
            'id' => 'firstname',
            'title' => __('First Name'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true


        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'Last Name',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'lastname',
            'label' => __('Last Name'),
            'id' => 'lastname',
            'title' => __('Last Name'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,

        ]
    );

    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
    //return $form;
}
```

Now, If i am printing **model** than it will return me all details but when i edit row data isn't filling up with form.

Is there anything i am missing with this ??

Also Model can also able to update data.

**but fails to render data.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code seems to be correct, But i found one issue with your code that is in your **Form**.

Change it to below than check it should work. It will Also resolves your problem you described here : [Magetno 2 : Get Customer FirstName and LastName with Custom Resource Model](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226918/magetno-2-get-customer-firstname-and-lastname-with-custom-resource-model)

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'firstname', // Update
    'text',
    [
        'name' => 'firstname',
        'label' => __('First Name'),
        'value' => 'Data',
        'id' => 'firstname',
        'title' => __('First Name'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true


    ]
);

$fieldset->addField(
    'lastname', // Change Here
    'text',
    [
        'name' => 'lastname',
        'label' => __('Last Name'),
        'id' => 'lastname',
        'title' => __('Last Name'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,

    ]
);
```

**Clear Cache and Check.**

Comment: Thanks It worked, I had to switch to php form. :( But now it worked .!!