# Magetno 2 : Get Customer FirstName and LastName with Custom Resource Model

Tags: customer, grid, uicomponent, adminform, magento2.2.4

I've custom model same as **Core Code**. (Vendor)

> ../Model/Grid.php

```
class Grid extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements 
GridInterface
{

const CACHE_TAG = 'customer_entity';


protected $_cacheTag = 'customer_entity';


protected $_eventPrefix = 'customer_entity';


protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\ResourceModel\Grid');
}

public function getEntityId()
{
    return $this->getData(self::ENTITY_ID);
}


public function setEntityId($entityId)
{
    return $this->setData(self::ENTITY_ID, $entityId);
}


public function getFirstname()
{
    return $this->getData(self::FIRSTNAME);
}


public function setFirstname($firstName)
{
    return $this->setData(self::FIRSTNAME, $firstName);
}


public function getLastname()
{
    return $this->getData(self::LASTNAME);
}


public function setLastname($lastName)
{
    return $this->setData(self::LASTNAME, $lastName);
}

public function getGroupId()
{
    return $this->getData(self::GROUP_ID);
}


public function setGroupId($groupId)
{
    return $this->setData(self::GROUP_ID, $groupId);
}
}
```

**Below is my interface**

```
interface GridInterface
{
 const ENTITY_ID = 'entity_id';
 const LASTNAME = 'lastname';
 const GROUP_ID = 'group_id';

 public function getEntityId();
 public function setEntityId($entityId);

 public function getLastname();
 public function setLastname($lastName);

 public function getGroupId();
 public function setGroupId($groupId);
}
```

**`When i am dumping model data in block form i am getting everything smilar as`**

> \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface

Note : I've added **`group_id`** for test purpose. And **`group_id`** is rendering to form Not **`Last Name`**.

I've cheked DB i think there's **`Index`** in **`customer_entity`** table for **`firstname`** and **`lastname`** that's why it can't render to form.

Check this.

[image: customer_entity]

What's solution for this ?? Any Help would be really appreciated.

If you need more details than Refer this: [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226816/magento-2-add-values-to-ui-component-fields)

Answer (score 1):

In your **custom_form.xml** file

```
<field name="your_field_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Model\Classname</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name label</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">[source_here]</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">your_field_id</item>
                    <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">-- Please Select --</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    In above -- Please Select -- is set as default custom message for dropdown.
```

Where you can set select dynamic option from this class,

`{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Model\Classname` using **toOptionArray()** method.

In **DataProvider.php** file,

```
<?php
namespace Yourmodule\Modulename\Model\Path;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request        
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }



public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    $itemId = $this->_request->getParam('page_id');

    if ( !empty($itemId) ) {
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $this->loadedData[$item->getId()] = $item->getData();
    }

    $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('form_item');

    if (!empty($data)) {
       //Do something
       $this->loadedData[$item->getId()] = $item->getData();
    } 
    return $this->loadedData;
}

}
```

**Another way to get data Using UI component.**

If you want get dafault value from another module using UI component

**Add this field in your custom_form.xml file**

```
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataProvider</item>
```

In **DataProvider.php** file,

```
<?php
namespace {Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Ui\Component\Form\Element;
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input
{
  /**
     * Prepare component configuration
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
      parent::prepare();

      $customValue = {Get Custom value};

      $config = $this->getData('config');

      if(isset($config['dataScope']) && $config['dataScope']=='your_field_id'){
        $config['default']= $customValue;
        $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
      }
    }
}
```